# does eclipse have a feature whereby I can find all instances of a specific label?

Tags: eclipse

I know I can just grep it, but I was wondering if Eclipse has a built in feature where I can highlight a public class member and get a list of all the places where it is being used in the package.

TIA

Comment: I think what you're looking for is highlight it, right click and choose > References > Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, right click on the member (I usually left click first and wait for Eclipse to highlight the member to make sure it knows what I want to search for) and choose `Open Call Hierarchy` for methods or `References > Workspace` for fields.

Answer (score 1):

1. Highlight the class member and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> to find references in the workspace
2. Click [image: group by package] *Group by Package* in the toolbar:
3. Click the *View Menu* arrow icon in the toolbar and select *Show as Tree* in the popup menu
4. Locate the desired package in the treeview and expand it to see results

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Eclipse for Java, but in CDT, you can right click and select `References->Project` to do this.